# How to set Filepicker in java swing to select only specific file ? eg . only files with .mo as extension

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

The file needs to be the input file for the tool to process it further.

I'm new to java.. would aprreciate any help.

Here's my current code I have for the filepicker.

```
private void browseButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
      String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
      textField1.setText(filename);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to read API documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

It reads:

> The following code pops up a file chooser for the user's home
>   directory that sees only .jpg and .gif images:
>
> ```
> JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
> FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
>     "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
> chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
> int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
> if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
>    System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
>         chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try to use FileFilter along with JFileChooser.
With file filter you can specify file type (say only .jpg files) to populate. here is link for ur reff.
*http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node99.html*

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom file filters like

```
class Chooser extends JFrame {
        JFileChooser chooser;
        String fileName;

        public Chooser() {
            chooser = new JFileChooser();

            int retVal = 0;
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new CUFilter());
            retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                // Ok logic
            }
        }
    }

    class CUFilter extends FileFilter {

        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if (f.isDirectory())
                return true;
            String s = f.getName();
            int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1)
                if (s.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase().equals("mo"))
                    return true;

            return false;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return "Accept .mo files only";
        }
    }
```